# SQL Report Builder Data Provider extensions

Tags: reporting-services, power-bi-report-server, sqlreportingservice

I have added a data provider extension to a Power BI Report Server to support PostgreSQL data sources for Paginated reports. I verified that creating a PostgreSQL data source on the server tests successfully. However, I need to add an extension to Report Builder so that I can design reports that use this data source. I cannot find any information on how to add an extension to the Report Builder. Only thing I found was about editing RSReportDesigner.config that is part of the SSDT. I have VS 2022 installed with SSDT enabled, but I do not have RSReportDesigner.config in the location that is specified in this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/rsreportdesigner-configuration-file?view=sql-server-ver16
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\RSReportDesigner.config

Any ideas how to add data providers to the Report Builder? Thanks